# Query azure table and output using xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, azure-table-storage

I am trying to get a list of items from my table in Azure and output it. I think my query structure is correct but how can I display the returned information to the listview?

```
    public async Task GetItems()
    {

        await infoTable.PullAsync( "info", infoTable.CreateQuery().Select(x => x.Information));

        ListView listview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);


    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the query result? If it's okay this question doesn't have anything to do with azure - rather with plain android/xamarin.

Comment: Yes I wrapped it in a try catch and it is failing, so it looks like there is an error in my query too.

Comment: Can you share the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add adapter to your listview.

If your list items are string, add this line.

```
   listview.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
```